# How to add product description in quick view section in bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to add product description in a quick view section of my big commerce store. So please any one how can i achieve this?

I have already tried to add this panel %%Panel.ProductDescription%% in to my Quickview.html file.but no luck.

Please any one..

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..Please check the quick view pop option of Madison Rose gold product of this following link.I would like to add production description in this pop up also..http://wristology.mybigcommerce.com/shop/

Comment: I have already tried to add this panel %%Panel.ProductDescription%% in to my Quickview.html file.but no luck.

Please any one..

Answer (score 1):

There is a BC variable that can be used to display the Product Description excerpt in quick view: %%GLOBAL_QuickViewProductDescription%% add it to QuickViewContent.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done some Ajax script call

you need to add below script inside "Panels/QuickViewContent.html" Panel.

it will fetch the description from it's product Page.

```
function processData(item){

    return function(data){

      var desc = jQuery(data).find("#ProductDescription .ProductDescriptionContainer").text();
    desc = desc.substr(0,450);
    jQuery("#QuickViewContent").find('.PriceRow').after("<div class='desc'>"+desc+"...<a class='read-more' href='"+item+"'>more</a></div>");

  }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var path = '%%GLOBAL_QuickViewProductURL%%';

        if(path!="") {
        path = path.replace("http://","//").replace("https://","//");

        var item = path;
        $.ajax({
          url: path,
          type: "GET",
           async: true,
             success: processData(item)
        });
        }

});
```